# Extending basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

(From Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra(4e). Section 3.5 . Problem 22)

---

Question: Suppose **S** is a 5-dimensional subspace of $R^6$. True or false.

a) Every basis for **S** can be extended to a basis for $R^6$ by adding one more vector

b) Every basis for $R^6$ can be reduced to a basis for **S** by removing one vector

---

For part a), the basis for **S** contains 5-dimensional vectors. How can adding another *5-dimensional* vector help create a 6-dimensional basis for $R^6$ ? Isn't there a dimension mismatch ? Similarly for part b) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that if $v$ is a vector in a $5$ dimensional vector space, then $v$ has $5$ components, i.e., that it looks something like $v=(x_1,\cdots ,x_5)$. This is not the case. In fact, vectors in general need not look anything like a list of numbers. For instance, the space of all continuous functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a linear space. The dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors in a basis (after proving all bases of a vector space have the same size).

Further hints:

a) Any linearly independent set of vectors in a vector space can be extended to a basis.

b) think of $\mathbb R^5$ sitting inside $\mathbb R^6$. Can you find a basis of $\mathbb R^6$ such that none of the basis vectors is in $\mathbb R^5$?

Comment: Your hints were helpful. This question was answered [here](http://math.uga.edu/~clayton/teaching/m215s10/homework/hw5solutions.pdf) on page 3. However, in the answer for part (a), the author suggests a relation between dimension of subspace S and components of $R^6$. That part of the reasoning would be incorrect, isn't it ?

Comment: no, the author suggests no such relationship. The author simply says that if you have 5 linearly independent vectors in a 6-dim vector space, then there are lots and lots of vectors that can be adjoined to the given 5 to obtain 6 linearly independent vectors. This is basically the definition of dimension.

Comment: There might be one, there might be many. How can we claim that there are "lots and lots" ? Does it come from the specific fact that we are dealing with $R^6$ here ?

Comment: if $v$ is one such vector, then $\alpha \cdot v$ is another such vector, for all scalars $\alpha \ne 0$. It is here assumed that the field of scalars in infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Since S is 5-D subspace of$ R^6$ ,so S consists of 5 Linearly Independent Six dimensional vectors.Now if you add one more Six dimensional vector((not 5-dimensional)  This is where u went wrong,) then you will have 6 Linearly indep. vectors which will span six dimensional space i.e $R^6$

For part (B)converse is true

Comment: there is no such thing as the dimension of a vector.

Comment: I mean components i.e v1=(x1,x2,x3) is 3-dimensional vector has 3 componts

Comment: vectors don't need to have components at all. The visual form of a vector says nothing about dimension.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I think you need a strict definition of that vector space with some conditions, e.g. relate to orthogonality to other vector subspaces. For example, if that vector space is linear function of other vector spaces, your questions would be false.

Please leave your comments.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are alluding to here, but this seems false.

Comment: Thanks, do we need conditions on the above mentioned vector?

Comment: conditions for what?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Conditions for orthogonality

Comment: there is no such thing as orthogonality in a vector space.